# How to pusshAsset depending on a user choice ? [apostrophe cms]

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm facing a new issue with Apostrophe. 
What should I do in my construct method, to push a js asset to the browser, according to a choice I made ?

Here is an exemple.

```
module.exports = {
name: 'lionjar-countdown-page',
label: 'Timer Page',
extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
addFields: [{
        name: 'bckImageTimer',
        label: 'Image de background',
        type: 'singleton',
        widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
        options: {
            limit: 1,
            aspectRatio: [1, 1]
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'timerType',
        label: "Sélectionnez l'animation d'arrière plan",
        type: 'select',
        choices: [
            { label: 'Aucune animation', value: '0', },
            { label: 'Particules légères', value: '1', },
            { label: 'Particules liées', value: '2', },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'timerHideNavigation',
        label: 'Masquer la navigation',
        type: 'boolean',
        help: "Masque le logo ainsi que les éléments de navigation"
    },
],
afterConstruct: function(self) {
    //console.log(self)
    //self.pageBeforeSend();
},
construct: function(self, options) {

    /*self.pageBeforeSend = function(req, callback) {
        // Careful, there isn't always a page object; we could be
        // rendering /login for instance
        if (req.data.page.timerType.length > 0) {
            //console.log(req.data.page.timerType);
            //
        }

        //console.log(req.data.page);
        return callback(null);
    };*/
    self.pushAsset('script', 'magic.min', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('script', 'magic2.min', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'always', { when: 'always' });

}
```

};

In my self.pageBeforeSend(), i get my "user" choice :
req.data.page.timerType

If its value is 1, I want to push this file : self.pushAsset('script', 'magic.min', { when: 'always' });

When I try pushing it in the self.pageBeforeSend(), the log says that it's too late to push my file to the frontend.

I've seen in the apostrophe doc, I can add args using {when:....} in my pushasset method, but I don't understand if this is the right way and how to do it.

Could any one show me the way please (if it's possible to do it)

Thanks,

Fabien

Comment: Is this choice different for different users / circumstances? When a site is in production and minify is set to true, all things using pushAsset have made their final choice and are concatenated and pushed to the correct scene, you don't get to dynamically make that choice per request. If you need to make this decision on the fly, you might want to make the determination in the template and add a script tag to your markup.

Comment: No, the choice is not for different users. "I", as an admin, decide if I want to show a type of animation or another. The thing is, I don't want to load unnecessary scripts. But your right, if I minify the site, I can't change my animations on the fly, without minifying again all the site. Could you be more specific with the "template markup" solution ? Please !

Comment: If you can push some bit of information to the appropriate template, or store it in the global doc (where you could check data.global.animation) then you could choose to load an additional asset with a script tag <script src='/js/animLib.js'></script> More about using the global doc/schema https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/settings.html#user-editable-global-settings

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow if I can, and I'll let you know if it's what I must do.

Comment: Hey Fabien, it would be great to get a conclusion to this question on SO. Did anything work for you?

Comment: Sorry, Stuart, I add too much work to do, and I didn't had time try your proposal. I'll do it asap, but their is still something confusing for me, with the self.play method.